# Are db_recovery_file_dest and db_recovery_file_dest_size parameter dynamic or static?

Tags: oracle-12c, parameter

Please have a look at the output below:

[image]

As I know we can check if the parameter is static or dynamic in Oracle using this query. Please correct me if I am wrong.

But I have seen something strange that "Even if db_recovery_file_dest and db_recovery_file_dest_size parameter are dynamic parameter, the data dictionary is showing FALSE value". As I understand from this SQL query, the mentioned parameters are static parameters.

I am not able to understand which one is correct or I am getting something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isinstance_modifiable` flag only tells you whether that parameter can be set differently for different instances (for RAC) or not. For the parameters you're looking at, it is false, meaning that all instances in a single RAC cluster must have the same values.

If you want to know when you can change a parameter, look at two other columns in that table:

- `isses_modifiable`: if `TRUE`, the parameter can be changed with `alter session`
- `issys_modifiable`: tells you about changes that can be made with `alter system`.

  - `IMMEDIATE` means yes and changes take effect immediately,
  - `DEFERRED` can be changed, but will only take effect at next start,
  - `FALSE` can only be changed if you used an `spfile` to start the instance, and changes only take effect on next start.

Complete details are available in the [`v$parameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn30176.htm#REFRN30176) documentation.